# Why is my catch-all route not working for some routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this in `routes.rb`:

```
resources :emergencies, except: [:new, :edit, :destroy], defaults: { format: :json }
match '*path', to: 'application#page_not_found', via: :all
```

I also have this in `application.rb`:

```
config.exceptions_app = self.routes
```

And my `application_controller.rb` looks like this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def page_not_found
    render json: { message: 'page not found' }, status: :not_found
  end
end
```

I have a set of test suites that tests the :new, :edit, and :destroy route. The routes for :edit and :destroy pass, returning the message page not found as expected, but the :new route returns `null`. Infact, anything like `/emergencies/anything` would render null, but something like `/emergences/new/new` would work correctly. Any idea on why this is happening and how I can fix it so that the route `/emergencies/new` is hitting the `page_not_found` action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `rake routes` to see how your routes lay out.

You will notice that the show route matches emergencies/:id (this includes emergencies/new, for example).

Routes match from the top down. Normally, resources declare the new route before the show route, to catch what would match the future declarations.

If you can, add a constraint to your show route, if not to match the id, at least to not match the new. or you could keep the resource routes and kick them to your page_not_found method in a before_filter in the controller...

Comment: I actually had a before_filter in the controller, and I was trying to get rid of the empty actions by using this catch-all way. Your explanation makes sense, and I could add a constraint, but that might make things messier than having empty actions in the controller. So I guess I'll revert back to using the before_action.

Comment: If you like, you should be able to delete the empty method definitions, and retain the before filter, to clean it up a little.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried that but get this error `AbstractController::ActionNotFound: The action 'new' could not be found for EmergenciesController`

Answer (score 0):

I see this already has an answer above, but there's a very straightforward catch all 301 redirect implementation when a route is not found. In the example below page not found redirects to root.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'static_pages#home'
.
.
. 

  # This is a catchall 301 redirect to home (does not help with (e) type errors --  MUST BE LAST )
  get "*path", to: redirect('/')
end
```